# Getting an error Cannot GET /api/course/update/:courseId while I make an api update in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, express, node.js-connect

I am a newbie in nodejs. I just created a CRUD project using Nodejs, Hbs, mongoose and express. While testing the update function on localhost. I am getting the ERROR `Cannot GET /api/course/update/:courseId`. I tried testing API by POSTMAN before. But everything is okay.
Here is my code:

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require("@handlebars/allow-prototype-access")
const dbConfig = require('./APP/config/db.config');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const db = require('./APP/models');
const Role = db.role;

db.mongoose
  .connect(`${dbConfig.URL}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }).then(() => {
  console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
  initial();
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
  process.exit();
});

app.engine('hbs', exphbs({
  handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(handlebars),
  defaultLayout: 'main',
  extname: '.hbs',
  layoutsDir: __dirname + '/VIEWS/layouts/'
}));

app.set('view engine','hbs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home',{msg:'This is home page'})
});

require('./APP/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./APP/routes/component.routes')(app);
require('./APP/routes/main.routes')(app);

app.listen(1000, () => {
  console.log('Server is running 1000');
})
```

component.routes.js

```
const controller = require('../controllers/component.controller');
const service = require('../routes/index');




module.exports = function (app) {

  app.get('/about-us', service.about_us);

  app.get('/main-course', service.main_course);

  app.get('/add-course', service.add_course);

  route.get('/update-course/:courseId', service.update_course)

  route.get('/detail-course', service.detail_course)


  //API
  app.get('/api/course/findAll',controller.findAll)

  app.post('/api/course/create', controller.createCourse)

  app.put('/api/course/update/:courseId', controller.updateCourse)

  app.delete('/api/course/delete/:courseId',controller.deleteCourse)

}
```

component.controller.js

```
const db = require("../models")
const Course = db.course;

exports.updateCourse =  function(req, res){
  if (!req.body.name) {
    return res.status(400).send({message: "Data to update can not be empty"})
  }

  const courseId = req.params.courseId;
  Course.findByIdAndUpdate(courseId, {
    name: req.body.name,
    // creationTime: new Date().getTime(),
    creationTime: req.body.creationTime,
    description: req.body.description
  },{useFindAndModify : false})
    .then(course => {
      if (!course) {
        return res.status(404).send({message: "Course not found with id"});
      }
      res.send(course)
    }).catch(err => {
    return res.status(500).send({message: "Error retrieving note with id"});
  });
}
```

What I'm doing wrong and how I can correct it?

Comment: I need some help, please

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a PUT to the update endpoint instead of a GET. The PUT method can be selected in postman just before the URL (GET / POST / PUT / DELETE / ....etc )